# How to compare @Today with a tag in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I know this is a weird question as there are other ways to do what I'm asking but I do have a use case here...
I'm trying to add a custom sprint style rule to turn any card containing a tag with the date of today red. Please note I live in Australia so our dates our dd/MM/yy.

The styling rule would be something like: Tags Contains @Today

When I try adding four different tags with values: 09/11/2020, 9/11/2020, 11/09/2020, and 11/9/2020 it still doesn't seem to turn the card red.

According to the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops-2019) the datetime format should match one of these four tags.

Is there some way I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure DevOps, the field tags type is String. If we configure styling rule like Tags Contains @Today in the Work item setting page, It will match @Today instead of datetime format. Please check the pic.

[image]

**Update1**

As a workaround, we could [add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-field) in the process and set the type to `Date/Time`, please check the pic below.

[image]

Then configure the field value in the work item and add styling rule like `DateTest = @Today`

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response again Vito, seems like you're answering all my questions lately!
The fact that the Tags is a string and that it doesn't work with the @Today function pretty much kills what I was trying to do unfortunately but you have answered my question so thank you.
Your workaround is exactly what I would like to be doing for my use case but can't as I'm locked into an XML process that disallows modifications :( One day we'll be able to change it!